# API exception message after upgrade to CiviCRM 5.48.0

Tags: civievent, upgrade, timezone

After a 'successful' upgrade to 5.48.0 there is an alert and System Status message:

```
Event timezone check failed
API Exception: Invalid field 'event_tz' while checking events for timezones.
```

No other problems are apparent.

Any thoughts on how I can address this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has come up twice before in chat. You need to completely replace the civi folder with the new code, not just extract files over it.

Comment: OK. Always do this with Drupal or WP, but this is a Joomla site, upgraded with 'install from folder', so failure to replace this not transparent.

Comment: We should probably update joomla docs, since this general issue has come up more often for joomla before.

Comment: Is direct replacement of the front & back end civi folders in joomla straightforward?

Comment: The docs say "If you run into any issues, such as the component not appearing to reflect the new version, you may need to first uninstall the existing version and then install the new version. Uninstalling CiviCRM will remove the component files, but will not impact your database in any way." So I guess that's how to do it.

Comment: Yes this was the way to go, thanks. I note that this installed Civi **without** any (even generic) civicrm.settings.php files and the Civi installation wouldn't function until the backed up versions were in place.

Comment: An important thing to note when doing this is that uninstalling also deletes all your Access Controls, so make sure you have a list before proceeding so you can reinstate these as a priority.

Comment: I removed administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/Check/Component/Event.php (well, in fact, I renamed it...). I just did it and apparently everything's alright. If that keeps working, I will have spared reinstalling the configuration files and worrying about ACL